# fixing layout on top of marker android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a layout on top of marker of `Google Map` because I have a custom info window with button but the buttons was working only for last marker so I am trying to fix layout on top of marker:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements InfoWindowAdapter {

static int Tab_Button_Of_List_And_Map_Is_Checked = 0,
        Setting_Button_Is_Clicked = 0, Marker_Number, Count_Of_Character,
        By_Proximity_And_By_Status_Is_Checked;

int k;

// static MAdapter Adapter;

static GoogleMap Google_Map;
public static ViewGroup Pop_Up;
View pop_1;
public static Marker Marker;

public static double[] latitude2, longitude2;
public static String Map_Current_city = "Lahore", Marker_title,
        String_Container_Of_Search_Text = "^";
public static TextView[] UnitsTitle, Units;
public static String[] Cities;
LatLng[] newyorker = {};
public static SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
public static ViewSwitcher View_Switcher;
public static Button Back_Button, Map_Button, Refresh_Button, List_Button,
        By_Proximity_Button, By_Status_Button, Setting_Button, Mud_Button,
        Details_Button;
public static TextView Marker_Title;

public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Array_Sort_Array_List,
        BY_STATUS_Array_List, BY_PROXIMITY_Array_List;

public static ListView List_View;

static OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener Info_Button_Listener;

static Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // / Layout Initialization ////////////////////////////////////

    Pop_Up = (ViewGroup) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.contentwidow, null);

    // ///////// End Of Layout Initialization//////////////////////

    latitude2 = new double[] { 24.983, 25.983, 26.983, 27.983, 28.983,
            29.983, 30.983, 31.983, 32.983, 33.983 };
    longitude2 = new double[] { 67.028, 68.028, 69.983, 71.983, 72.983,
            73.983, 74.983, 75.983, 76.983, 77.983 };

    // //// putting the textviews id for unit in array /// //

    TextView First_First_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_first_layout_text_1);
    TextView First_Second_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_Second_layout_text_1);
    TextView First_Third_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_Third_layout_text_1);
    TextView First_Fourth_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_Fourth_layout_text_1);
    TextView Second_First_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_first_element_text_1);
    TextView Second_Second_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_second_element_text_1);
    TextView Second_Third_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_third_element_text_1);
    TextView Second_Fourth_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_fourth_text_1);
    TextView Third_First_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_first_element_text_1);
    TextView Third_Second_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_second_element_text_1);
    TextView Third_Third_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_third_text_1);
    TextView Third_Fourth_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_fourth_text_1);
    TextView Fourth_First_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_first_text_1);
    TextView Fourth_Second_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.fourth_second_text_1);
    TextView Fourth_Third_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_Third_Text_1);
    TextView Fourth_Fourth_Title = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_fourth_text_1);

    Units = new TextView[] { First_First_Title, First_Second_Title,
            First_Third_Title, First_Fourth_Title, Second_First_Title,
            Second_Second_Title, Second_Third_Title, Second_Fourth_Title,
            Third_First_Title, Third_Second_Title, Third_Third_Title,
            Third_Fourth_Title, Fourth_First_Title, Fourth_Second_Title,
            Fourth_Third_Title, Fourth_Fourth_Title };

    Cities = new String[] { "Hyderabad", "Karachi", "Islamabad",
            "Faisalabad", "Multan", "RawalPindi", "NawabShah", "Sukkur",
            "Sanghar", "Lahore" };

    // ////// putting the title of units in array //////// //

    TextView First_First_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_first_Layout_text_2);
    TextView First_Second_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_Second_layout_text_2);
    TextView First_Third_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_Third_layout_text_2);
    TextView First_Fourth_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.First_fourth_layout_text_2);
    TextView Second_First_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_first_element_text_2);
    TextView Second_Second_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_second_text_2);
    TextView Second_Third_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_third_element_text_2);
    TextView Second_Fourth_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Second_fourth_text_2);
    TextView Third_First_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_first_element_text_2);
    TextView Third_Second_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_second_element_text_2);
    TextView Third_Third_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_third_text_2);
    TextView Third_Fourth_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Third_fourth_text_2);
    TextView Fourth_First_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_First_text_2);
    TextView Fourth_Second_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_second_text_2);
    TextView Fourth_Third_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_third_text_2);
    TextView Fourth_Fourth_Unit = (TextView) Pop_Up
            .findViewById(R.id.Fourth_fourth_text_2);

    UnitsTitle = new TextView[] { First_First_Unit, First_Second_Unit,
            First_Third_Unit, First_Fourth_Unit, Second_First_Unit,
            Second_Second_Unit, Second_Third_Unit, Second_Fourth_Unit,
            Third_First_Unit, Third_Second_Unit, Third_Third_Unit,
            Third_Fourth_Unit, Fourth_First_Unit, Fourth_Second_Unit,
            Fourth_Third_Unit, Fourth_Fourth_Unit };

    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    for (Marker_Number = 0; Marker_Number < 10; Marker_Number++) {

        LatLng NewYorker = new LatLng(latitude2[Marker_Number],
                longitude2[Marker_Number]);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        Google_Map = mapFragment.getMap();

        Marker = Google_Map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                NewYorker).title(Cities[Marker_Number]));

        Google_Map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(NewYorker,
                15));

        // Google_Map.setInfoWindowAdapter(this);

    }

    Google_Map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        int a = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
            ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.contentwidow,
                    linear, false);

            if (a == 0) {
                a=1;
                Log.d("chal", "gaya");  
                        linear.addView(view, 0);
                Log.d("hello", "world");
                linear.bringToFront();


            } 

            else if(a==1) {
                Log.d("1111","222");
                    linear.removeViewAt(0); 
                        a=0;

                    }


            return true;
        }
    });



}

@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

    return null;

}

@Override
public View getInfoWindow(final Marker arg0) {

    Pop_Up = (ViewGroup) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.contentwidow, null);


    Mud_Button = (Button) Pop_Up.findViewById(R.id.mud_log_button);

    MainActivity.Mud_Button
            .setOnTouchListener(MainActivity.Info_Button_Listener);
    MainActivity.Info_Button_Listener = new OnInfoWindowElemTouchListener(
            Mud_Button, null, null) {
        @Override
        protected void onClickConfirmed(View v) {
            // if (Setting_Button_Is_Clicked == 0) {

            Log.d("Setting", "Buttonclicked");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "setting button" + Marker_Number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();

        }
    };

    // /////// Starting of Setting button //////////// //

    return Pop_Up;

}

// /////////// ENDING OF THE UNIMPLEMENTED METHOPD OF INFO WINDOW ADAPTER
// //////

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    boolean ret = false;
    int bottomOffsetPixels = 0;
    // Make sure that the infoWindow is shown and we have all the needed
    // references
    if (Marker != null && Marker.isInfoWindowShown() && Google_Map != null
            && Pop_Up != null) {
        // Get a marker position on the screen
        Point point = Google_Map.getProjection().toScreenLocation(
                Marker.getPosition());

        // Make a copy of the MotionEvent and adjust it's location
        // so it is relative to the infoWindow left top corner
        MotionEvent copyEv = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        copyEv.offsetLocation(-point.x + (Pop_Up.getWidth() / 2), -point.y
                + Pop_Up.getHeight() + bottomOffsetPixels);

        // Dispatch the adjusted MotionEvent to the infoWindow
        ret = Pop_Up.dispatchTouchEvent(copyEv);
    }
    // If the infoWindow consumed the touch event, then just return true.
    // Otherwise pass this event to the super class and return it's result
    return ret || super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
}
```

}

Comment: pls elaborate your question..

Comment: actually i want to fix layout on top of that is inflating on a layout that contain map fragement i have multiple marker but i want tyo fix layout on top of marker but the inflated layout was fix on the center of parent layout

Comment: is there any way to acess custom info window functionalities on multiple marker that have button i was fail in that so i am trying this

Comment: sorry ... still confused.. as i think you have a map with many markers and when you click marker you want to show popup on map which having a button.. am i right?

Comment: yes you are absolutely right info window also shown on all the markers with the button but the button click is just only accessable on the last marker

Comment: ok i got your problem.. in dispatchTouchEvent() you are calling the last marker.. this is because in that for loop your **marker** instance variable of **Marker** class having last marker so it shows only last marker

Comment: kindly give me the suggestion to overcome to this problem to thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are doing it the wrong way..
please use this method of google map api for trapping event of marker rather than dispatchEvent() method,then it will work:--

```
googlemap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                }
    });
```